# How to fix "stdin:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (global 'lua') " error?

Tags: lua

I am trying out exercise problems is Programming in Lua by Roberto Ierusalimschy.

I am having problem with chapter 1 question 1.1

```
function fact(n)

   if n < 0 then 

      return print("entered number is negative")

   elseif n == 0 then

      return 1
   else 

      return n*fact(n-1)
   end

end
```

I expect an output "Entered number is negative" when I give fact(-1) (Any negative number not only -1 inside fact), and factorial of given positive number

Comment: Can I ask what is wrong?  Aside from a bad return or 2. What is your problem with the script?

Comment: I am not getting the desired output. After loading the script and i give fact(-1) i am getting stack overflow and it is showing me some stack traceback results.

Comment: The code works fine for me. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm just guessing, but maybe there's something wrong with a variable you pass to the function.

Comment: The code also works with me, so if it's not working for you, it seems we're not getting the full information. As @luther said, please follow the directions in the link, and include all information relevant to the code, even if you think it doesn't matter. For example, are you doing `print(fact(-1))`, or are you just doing `fact(-1)`. Or where does the error message from your title come from? Your title makes it seem like you're using a variable called `lua`, but no such variable exists in your code.

Comment: Now code is working for me after i removed "return print("entered number is negative") to "print("entered number is negative"). Thanks for your help everyone